# I switched my project to x64 and got an error

Tags: c++, 64-bit

I have this project that I'm working on for a while now, and it was working just fine before I switched from releasing an x86 version to an x64 one.

This is the line of code where the error appeared:

```
ReadProcessMemory(a.hProcess, LPCVOID(b->Ebx + 8), LPVOID(&c), 4, 0);
```

I don't understand assembly but when the Error appeared at `b->Ebx` I changed it to `b->Rbx`. and it compiled and run but it didn't do the job it was supposed to do.

Am I using the wrong register?

**After a little bit of debugging**

```
pe_dos_h = PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER(pe_image);

pe_nt_h = PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS(DWORD(pe_image) + pe_dos_h->e_lfanew);

//error when trying to assign a value or access the signature in nt-headers
//ERROR: read access violation
IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* pe_nt_h->Signature == IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE;//0x00004550-PE00
```

The pe_image is raw data copied from a PE(.exe) file. Is the difference is in handling x86 PE image vs x64 one?

This is a simplified version of the code. If you think the problem is out of the scope of this piece of code let me know.

Comment: Is _WIN64 defined?

Comment: @273K I just checked and yes it is, when I add this condition ``#if defined( _WIN64 )`` it highlights the code inside of it.

Comment: Is there a way to debug the ``IMAGE_NT_HEADERS`` struct to see if it's set up correctly?
if it's not we would know that the action of setting the value of the ``IMAGE_NT_HEADERS`` is not valid for x64.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the way I was defining the `IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER`, In x64 architecture, I had to use the x64-specific datatype `IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER64`.

and also when casting `pe_nt_h = PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS(DWORD_PTR(pe_image) + pe_dos_h->e_lfanew);`

I had to use `DWORD_PTR` instead of just `DWORD` because it was missing some bits.

here is the solution code for the simplified version I provided in the post:

```
  PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pe_dos_h = PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER(pe_image);

  PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS64 pe_nt_h = PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS(DWORD_PTR(pe_image) + pe_dos_h->e_lfanew);
```